# how to Detect if Keyboard is shown in Xcode UI test

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitest

I am writing a UI text in swift under the new Xcode 7 UI test framework.
the requirement is to test whether the system keyboard is shown in an app.
can someone give me a clue on how to do that? thanks

Comment: BTW, when I was trying to look for the accessibility in the debug mode of the keyboard, I can't not see it in the app. so I guess that since it is a system keyboard, so we can not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two observers

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardVisible:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardHidden:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

func keyboardVisible(notif: NSNotification) {
    print("keyboardVisible")
}

func keyboardHidden(notif: NSNotification) {
    print("keyboardHidden")
}
```

Whenever the keyboard is visible `keyboardVisible` will be called and whenever the keyboard is hidden `keyboardHidden` will be called.

Comment: I add this into the UI test code, but it does not work

Comment: here is my codeoverride 
`func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: XCUIApplication())
    }`

Comment: Should we use NotificationCenter in a UI Test? I doubt it.

Answer (score 32):

Try this check:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.keyboards.count > 0, "The keyboard is not shown")
```

Or check for specific keyboard keys like:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.keyboards.buttons["Next:"].exists, "The keyboard has no Next button")
```

You can also control interactions on the keyboard:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.keyboards.buttons["Next:"].tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the keyboard count check didnt work on one of my apps (it returned a count of 1 even when the keyboard was hidden), so amended it slightly:

```
private func isKeyboardShown() -> Bool {
    return XCUIApplication().keyboards.keys.count > 0
}
```

Comment: could you modify your answer above to read `private func...` instead of `private fund...`"

Comment: `XCUIApplication().keyboards.element(boundBy: 0).exists` also works